# PHP Mailing class won't fill message with HTML

Tags: php, email, message, send

I have a PHP mailing class. The problem is the email message with won't come with HTML it's just plain text.. i bet any other programmers sees my mistake.. hope some of you can!

Code for calling my functions :

```
    GhostMailer::setHTML(true);
    GhostMailer::setSender(Input::get('emailfrom'));
    GhostMailer::addRecipient(Input::get('emailto'));
    GhostMailer::setSubject(Input::get('subject'));
    GhostMailer::setReturnAddress(Input::get('emailfrom'));
    GhostMailer::setMessage(Input::get('email'));
    GhostMailer::getHeaders();
    GhostMailer::send();
```

The `send()` function :

```
public static function send ()
{

    $message = self::$message;
    $head    = "";
    foreach ( self::$header as $key => $value ) { $head.= $key . ': ' . $value . self::EOL; }

    // If attachments given
    if ( count ( self::$attachments ) > 0 )
    {

        $separator = md5 ( time() );
        self::setHeaders ( 'Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $separator . '"' );

        $head = "";
        foreach ( self::$header as $key => $value ) { $head.= $key . ': ' . $value . self::EOL; }
        $head.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . self::EOL;
        $head.= "This is a MIME encoded message." . self::EOL . self::EOL;

        // Preparing the message with proper formatting, charsets, content-types and encoding.
        $head .= "--" . $separator . self::EOL;
        $head .= "Content-Type: text/" . ( self::$isHTML ? 'html' : 'plain' ) . "; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . self::EOL;
        $head .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . self::EOL . self::EOL;
        $head .= $message . self::EOL . self::EOL;
        $head .= "--" . $separator . self::EOL;

        $message = "";

        // Attach all given attachments to the mail
        foreach ( self::$attachments as $attached )
        {

            $tmp      = explode ( "/", $attached );
            $filename = end ( $tmp );

            $file_size = filesize ( $attached );


            try // Try to open the file
            {

                $handle  = fopen ( $attached, "r" );
                $content = fread ( $handle, $file_size );
                fclose ( $handle );

            }
            catch ( Exception $e )
            {

                die ( "[GhostMailer] FATAL ERROR IN ATTACHMENTS: Could not open file; Stacktrace: " . $e->getMessage () );

            }

            $content = chunk_split ( base64_encode ( $content ) );

            // attachment
            $head .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . self::EOL;
            $head .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . self::EOL;
            $head .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . self::EOL . self::EOL;
            $head .= $content . self::EOL . self::EOL;
            $head .= "--" . $separator . self::EOL;

        }

    }

    foreach ( self::$recipients as $recipient )
    {

        if ( ! mail (
            $recipient,
            self::$subject ,
            $message ,
            $head
        )
        ) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: You're putting the message in the headers, then clearing it.  Then using it in the `mail()` call.

Comment: That is now fixed. forgot to delete one line. But now i get text with html in it. but i set isHTML() to true so it's supposed to handle those html tags..

Comment: `( self::$isHTML ? 'html' : 'plain' )` looks to be right.  My guess is either your Input class or the setMessage method is escaping or encoding the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you delete the following line:

```
$message = "";
```

It should work as expected. Otherwise, please provide your setMessage method code.

Edit regarding the OP Comment:

If you want to remove the html tags have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$stripedMessage = strip_tags($message);
```

And then send $stripedMessage instead of $message;.

Comment: What i meant is, delete the line i've pointed out. You are re-setting the $message variable to an empty string, and then sending it.

Comment: Okay my message content shows up but with HTML tags.. i have set isHTML() to true.. do you mind looking for that too @taxicala

Comment: Just edited my answer, but i'm not sure if thats what you wanted.

Comment: Will look into the second part thanks sir! accepted is as an answer! @taxicala

Comment: I don't think he wants it stripped, but that would be useful for $isHTML false.

Comment: Okay now it strips all the tags out of it.. but if i make a html email in the text editor i don't see the things i made in html i just see plain text.. Any thoughts ? @taxicala

Comment: And maybe you know an option @Devon (check last comment before this one) Thanks in advance

Comment: I commented on the OP.  My assumption is the HTML is encoded before it gets to the `send()` function.  You shouldn't need any function to display HTML.

Comment: Whatever i do i don't receive my mail in html... @Devon

Comment: Did you read through my comment and make sure the Input class or setMessage function isn't doing something?  It'd be pretty easy to diagnose.  Use `$message = $_GET['email'];` in the send function.

Comment: uhm i still use : `self::setMessage ( $message );` because i'm in Laravel 4.2 framework so i call the `GhostMailer::setMessage(Input::get('email'));` line to fill the variable `$message` with content @Devon